# Virtualbox: Retrieve data from Vagrant Ubuntu environment

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I had configured a virtual Ubuntu droplet with Vagrant for the development purpose on my Ubuntu system. Now, I am unable to start the virtual machine, on using the command `vagrant up`, following error is coming up:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "9295efec-36d1-4aed-932d-ddd5785df28b", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-eth0' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage: error: Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage: error: One of the kernel modules was not successfully loaded. Make sure that no kernel modules from an older version of VirtualBox exist. Then try to recompile and reload the kernel modules by executing '/sbin/vboxconfig' as root (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

I am not sure what caused this error as I hadn't made any changes in the configuration. Anyways, now I am looking to retrieve the data which was stored in the virtual machine as the backup data I have is not fully updated. 
Any advice would be much helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is when the wrong modules have been loaded or loaded with this e.g (/sbin/vboxconfig), 
open a shell with sudo, and try the following

```
>sudo su - 
>/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup"

Unloading modules: vboxdrv
Loading modules: vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv
```

Make sure on the latest version of virtuabox 5.0.12 or above.
Issue on Virtualbox.org related to this https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14723